# Word "func" is underlined with dashes but no error

Tags: swift, xcode

This is not a major question. But, I don't know from where it comes. I've got like below image,

[image]

And I don't know from where this underlining is coming. As I said in the title it's not a warning or an error, but I find it's strange and that bothers me. Does anyone knows how to get rid of it?

Comment: You just click on the line?!

Comment: Clean->Build. You will get an error or the underline won't be there.

Comment: try to reopen Xcode

Comment: You can also clean manually the DerivedData `cd ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData` and delete all files/folders

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sometimes happens for me when SourceKit crashed or symbolication does not work for some other reason.

What I usually do is close the file (command + shift + w) and reopen it. If this does not help restarting Xcode often makes the problem go away.

Answer (score 2):

Happened to me before, this fixed it:

1- Force Quit XCode (Command + Q).

2- Then enter XCode again

3- Press (Command + K) to clean the build.

4- Press (Command + B) to built again from the start.

Error should be gone.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

That happened because of you tapped `cmd+;` that's shortcut keyboard key for grammar check in `XCode`. When you keep tapping `cmd+;` it's shown next grammar mistake. It's just grammar check that's it.

[image]

To check `XCode - key Bindings` list -> `cmd+,`

To remove change your class file it will disappear automatically.